# Using latd as a "client"

Tags: linux, networking

I'm sure my terminology is wrong or at least somewhat off, so please bear with me...

I need to connect a simple clock display (NOT a timekeeper, just a display!) running an embedded Debian 7 to the network cable that formerly connected to a LAT terminal server which provided a serial port for the original clock display to read for data.  So the ORIGINAL system was (and yes, it was/is a one way communication link):

`(host)->LAT Terminal Server->(serial port #7)->Clock Display`

The new system will remove the terminal server to become:

`(host)->New clock Display`

Unfortunately, I need to handle the communication between the host and LAT server and convert it to serial output (the clock display cannot transmit data back to the host).

I *think* that `latd` will handle (almost?) all of this for me, but the documentation I can find is extremely lacking and when I went looking at the [project itself](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linux-decnet/) (on SourceForge), the documentation wiki begins (and ends) with "DECnet for Linux is no longer supported."

I found man pages for `latcp` but they completely fail to document nearly *half* of the parameters that seem to be required to create a "reverse LAT" device.  For example:

> The syntax for creating a reverse LAT port is:
> `latcp -A -p tty -V learned_service [-R rem_port] [-H  rem_node] [-Q] [-8]`
> The  `tty`  name  should start `/dev/lat` and must not exist. The `-Q`
> flag indicates that connections to the service is queued. If you
> connect  to a queued service and it is busy then your connection
> will be forced to wait until it is available. You must use  this
> flag for printer services on DECserver 90L terminal servers, and
> in this case the service name must also be empty. NOTE that  the
> `-Q` flag is the opposite way round to that on Tru64 Unix(r).
> The `-8` flag tells `latd` not to muck about with the data. Normally
> `latd` will transmit a BREAK if  a  NUL  character  is  typed,  `-8`
> disables  this  behaviour for ports with (eg) printers or modems
> attached.

Notice that the `-V`, `-R` and `-H` parameters are not even mentioned, despite the `-V` apparently being a *required* parameter!

So, my question is how to use `latcp` to create a device that basically looks like a serial port that my clock display can read to receive time records from the host?  I think it is something like the line below:

`latcp -A -p /dev/lat/truetime -V no_idea -R 7 -8`

I'm guessing about the `-r` parameter because there does not appear to be any way to associate the reverse lat device with a port from the LAT terminal server.  Of course, I could be completely misunderstanding what `latd` provides and be completely out of luck.

Comment: Debian 7 support ended in May 2018.

Comment: @ChanganAuto... very helpful.  Unfortunately, our hardware vendor prepares the system image for the tiny little CPU boards we use and we cannot change it if we still want the board to boot in under 5 seconds (which we do).  We can add packages, though, hence my question.